# Flutter Cast for iOS and and Android devices

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I would love if anyone can point me in the right direction for a good solution for casting in flutter.
Ive tried many solutions
ie: https://github.com/iansamz/flutter_google_cast_button.git

or the dart_chromecast: https://pub.dev/packages/dart_chromecast

to no avail.

I would love a solution for both iOS and Android if anyone can direct me on how to create a plugin for this or any example I would love to hear from anyone.